# Cast an object X to an object Y who inherits of X

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class X who herits of TcpClient, and a TcpListener. I'd like that when I call the AcceptTcpClient(), which return a TcpClient, I'll get a X class, or be able to "cast" this TcpClient to my class X.

I can't do something like (X)TcpClient so i'm a little lost.

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: You cannot do that. Here is similar question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/8c400d6f-c2e0-412a-b30e-165974c9bd0d

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can only downcast if the object has the correct runtime type.

Instead you could create an adapter with a constructor that accepts a TcpClient, but then adds its own functionality.

```
class MyTcpClientAdapter
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient;

    public MyTcpClientAdapter(TcpClient tcpClient) {
        this.tcpClient = tcpClient;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought. Is it possible to set the "base" on an herited class?